# iphone doesnt render web pages properly

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have this problem with one of the mobile websites i built, there is a DIV which wraps the whole content, and it is 612 px wide, and has 14px of a padding on each side (left, right) this makes the column to be 640px

but when viewing the site in an iphone 4, there are a lot of white space on the sides of the site, can anyone give me some clue?

cheers

Comment: What's the site, and/or the CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

in the `head` of you HTML.

Comment: thats awesome! but i had to use <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5"/> to get it to the right size